# Access an element in a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am programming a comment page where I also want the functionality to delete a comment. But how do I access the elements, like inside the `<p>` and `<span>` tags in my class .commentdiv, if the .commentdiv has been assigned to a JavaScript variable?
A bit flumsy to explain, but check the code below.

I want to use that information to use an AJAX-call and delete the matching comment in my database.

So this is hopefully quite a simple thing, but I am still unable to find the answer to my problem. The `filter()` function called upon the parentDiv object doesn't work.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="commentdiv">
    <p>$comment</p>
    <a href="#" class="deletecomment">Delete comment</a>
    <span class="commname">$name</span>, <span class="commtimestamp">$time</span> 
</div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
var parentDiv = $(this).parent();   
var name = parentDiv.filter('.commname').innerHTML;
var comment = parentDiv.filter('p').innerHTML;
var timestamp = parentDiv.filter('.commtimestamp').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thats not PHP... Also Id's must be unique, so you can't use it for repeated elements like that, use a class instead.

Comment: Note: since you use jQuery, you should use `.html()` instead of `.innerHTML` ?

Comment: Right, forgot to double check what I wrote! Of course it's JavaScript and I have used classes.
@EJTH Isn't html() and .innerHTML the same thing?

Comment: You could use HTML 5's data attributes to identify items, and access them via jQuery.data (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).
Also, you could use the jQuery.find method to search the children for a specific element. There are plenty of examples of how you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery you should use [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You should also check out many of the tutorials about how to use jquery or javascript to interact with the dom. [Google](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20interact%20with%20dom%20tutorial) is your friend and [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery) have a decent beginners tutorial.

To access:

```
<p>$comment</p>
$('.commentdiv p:first').html(); //gets the $comment value from the above

<span class="commname">$name</span>, 
$('span .comname').html();    //gets the $name value from the above

<span class="commtimestamp">$time</span> 
$('span .commtimestamp').html();  //gets the $time value from the above
```

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't this remove all my comments? I just want to access the elements in which I click the 'deletebutton'. How would I write that?

Comment: The code above just gets the values within the specified html tags. It does nothing else. After that its up to you to do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

I approached my problem a bit differently. Instead of going up a level to the .commentdiv, I searched for the siblings of the .deletebutton instead with the code below:

```
var name = $(this).siblings(".commname").html();
var comment = $(this).siblings("p").html();
var timestamp = $(this).siblings(".commtimestamp").html();
```

Hurray!